# Determining an Appropriate Locate Fee Threshold for Short Selling Based on Expected Return

Tags: programming, expected-value

I'm working on an automated stock trading program and often consider short selling as part of my strategy. For each potential short sale, there's an associated "locate fee" that I have to pay. My trades are driven by a predictive model that provides an expected return for each trade.

I'm trying to determine a dynamic threshold for the locate fee based on the expected return from the model. For instance, if the model predicts an expected return of 3.5% on a trade, I might be willing to accept locate fees up to, say, 1% (just as an example). However, I don't want to use a fixed ratio or constant for this threshold, as it should adjust based on the expected return.

Ideally, I'd like a mathematical or statistical approach to determine this threshold that doesn't rely on manually set constants or the variance of the model's predictions. The goal is to have a formula where, given an expected return, it outputs the maximum acceptable locate fee for that trade.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can suggest a sophisticated approach to determine this dynamic threshold?

I have thought using

```
import math

def threshold_fee(expected_return):
    """Determine the maximum locate fee based on a scaled and shifted sigmoid function."""
    
    # Parameters for the sigmoid function
    a = 1.05
    b = 2
    c = 4
    
    # Calculate the adjusted sigmoid function
    adjusted_sigmoid = a / (1 + math.exp(-b * (expected_return - c)))
    
    # Return the adjusted sigmoid value as the maximum locate fee
    return expected_return * adjusted_sigmoid
```

Its seems fine for threshold_fee(3.5), but for threshold_fee(1) and threshold_fee(5) it does not make sense. When the expected_value small, I am not willing give back too much of that EV to locate fee. When the EV becomes larger, then au contraire I am fine to give back more of the EV in locate. For instance, if the model gives in general 3.5% per trade, than I am wiling to give back 1% in locate fees, if the EV is 8%, I could give back 3% per trade in locate fees.